# bower version issue

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, bower

I have a problem with VS2015 Community and Bower plugin.

I tried to install bootstrap version 3.3.7 (3.3.6 and early).

You can see my `bower.json` file:

[image: bower.json] 
But I always see only the latest version downloaded in libs folder:

[image: screen of bootstrap file from libs]
Can someone explain why bower ignores the requested version?

Comment: If you want to make your question more useful, post text as text. It should be obvious, that screen shots escape text searches.

Answer (score 0):

Found reason, it was a old Git version installed issue. 
Not VS or Bower problem. When I updated Git to latest and clear Bower cache I got correct version of libs. Don't know why Bower or Git don't show error when it can't execute my request correctly!